# DataBind on a DropDownList throws exception even though no index is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

So i am getting this error

```
{"'drpButton1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.\r\nParameter name: value"}
```

From everything i can read this is because the DropDownList either had existing items or had a selected index or value which is not in the new databound items.

But the thing is i can GUARANTEE that there are no existing items in the object and i can also say with confidence that there has not been an index selected that could be out of range.

Here is what the DropDownList object looks like directly before the .databind() call.

[image: DropDownlList object before the databind() call]

Here it is directly after the databind() call that has caused all the explosions.
[image]

My list object contains 7 items and in particular it contains the item that the databind method randomly decides to pick.

But here is the kicker i literally fill up 8 dropdowns with the EXACT same data and it works on the first dropdown just fine. No idea why the second one explodes.

EDIT: here is the code that does the binding:

Here is a snippet from the load method. the first call succeeds the second one fails but it doesn't fail all the time.

```
       private void LoadShortCodeDropDownData()
        {
            // Initilization junk to get the resultList to use.

   base.LoadListDropDown(drpButton0, (IList)resultList, "DeviceShortCodeIndexID", "DeviceShortCodeName", select);
                MessageTextEnabled(drpButton0);

                base.LoadListDropDown(drpButton1, (IList)resultList, "DeviceShortCodeIndexID", "DeviceShortCodeName", select);
                MessageTextEnabled(drpButton1);
}

    protected void LoadListDropDown(DropDownList dropDown, IList list, string valueField, string textField, string insertItem)
    {
        LoadListDropDown(dropDown, list, valueField, textField);
        //dropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(insertItem, ""));
    }

protected void LoadListDropDown(DropDownList dropDown, IList list, string valueField, string textField)
        {
            dropDown.DataSource = list;
            dropDown.DataValueField = valueField;
            dropDown.DataTextField = textField;
            dropDown.DataBind();
        }
```

EDIT2: I think the real question i have here is how is the databind picking which item to select? I noticed that the first dropdown that gets databound randomly selects the first value in the list while the second one tries to bind to the very last one in the list for some reason.

Comment: can you post your actual code?

Comment: Can you add the code that does the `.DataBind()`?

Comment: try to set `dropDown.SelectedValue=null; dropDown.Items.Clear();` before you assign datasource value. Check this for more details - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/666808/asp-net-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-is-persisted-which-results-in-exception-if-the-control-is-databound-second-time

Comment: Re: your second edit:  THAT is very interesting.  What type of object is `resultList`?  What does `MessageTextEnabled` do?  Is this happening on the first load or after postback?  Normally, unless you tell it either which items or what index to select, the DropDownList will appear to "select" the first item.

Comment: Also:  are you certain that these methods are being called only once in a page load?  You could be successfully binding on the first run through and then failing on some subsequent run.

Comment: @AnnL. ResultList is a custom IList object that was auto generated. MessageTextEnabled only reads the index of the object and enables or disables a text field based on the index value. Also yes i am certain, i am running through the debugger and they are only getting hit one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this happening on the first load of the page, or after a postback?  Because if it's a postback, you very well could have `SelectedIndex == 0` just by default.

I can't guarantee that this will solve the problem, but you could try adding

```
dropDown.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

... to the top of your second `LoadListDropDown` overload.

Comment: This works but now it refuses to assign values later on. No error it just doesn't assign the correct one. No idea how this fixes it because the index was never assigned but what ever.

Answer (score 0):

I've run in to this before, and I dont think you can bind the same list to multiple drop downs.

Comment: While it's true that you can't have multiple dropdowns share the exact same ListItem objects, doing a DataBind ought to create new ListItem objects every time.  Binding multiple dropdowns to the same data shouldn't be a problem.